# SQL aliasing with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alias

I'm looking to select all fields from my Report, Player, and Fixture tables where the FixtureID from the Report table matches @FixtureID (selected from a combobox). However, I'm having trouble getting the aliasing to work correctly- I've tried to alias the Player table in the same way as Report and Fixture, but this throws an error as well.

```
               SELECT 
                    r.*,
                    Player.*,
                    f.*,
                    isNull(Player.PlayerFirstName + ' ' + Player.PlayerLastName, ' ') AS 'PlayerName' 
                FROM 
                    Report AS r, Fixture AS f
                INNER JOIN Player ON Player.PlayerID = r.PlayerID
                INNER JOIN f ON f.FixtureID = r.FixtureID
                WHERE
                    r.FixtureID = @FixtureID
                ORDER BY 
                    ReportDate
```

The error states: "The multi-part identifier "r.PlayerID" could not be bound".

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the Report table contains a column called PlayerID?

Comment: The Report table definitely contains PlayerID, yes. My intention is to be able to view a Report on each Player within each Fixture- if that answers your question regarding the cross joining tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT r.*
    ,Player.*
    ,f.*
    ,isNull(Player.PlayerFirstName + ' ' + Player.PlayerLastName, ' ') AS 'PlayerName'
FROM Report AS r
INNER JOIN Player ON Player.PlayerID = r.PlayerID
INNER JOIN Fixture AS f ON f.FixtureID = r.FixtureID
WHERE r.FixtureID = @FixtureID
ORDER BY ReportDate
```